# SAS Format could not be loaded

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Good morning,
I have a small problem in a SAS code that I don't understand, what exactly is it and how can I solve this problem? the code is executed by the platform SAS knowing if I execute on my side it works normally

```
MPRINT(SIN1):   proc sql ;
MPRINT(SIN1):   create table WORK.Maj_SIN as select distinct A.* , B.NUM_SIN as NUM_SIN1, B.DAT_MVT as DAT_MVT1 from TAB1
as A left join TAB2 as B on (A.NUM_SIN=B.NUM_SIN and A.DAT_MVT=B.DAT_MVT);
ERROR: Format $TRCHAGE could not be loaded. The default format will be used.
ERROR: Format $NB could not be loaded. The default format will be used.
NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.MAJ_SIN decreased size by 63.04 percent. 
      Compressed is 17 pages; un-compressed would require 46 pages.
NOTE: Table WORK.MAJ_SIN created, with 4300 rows and 113 columns.      

MPRINT(SIN1):   data WORK.Maj_SIN;
MPRINT(SIN1):   set WORK.Maj_SIN;
MPRINT(SIN1):   IF NUM_SIN1 ne "" THEN DELETE ;
MPRINT(SIN1):   drop NUM_SIN1 DAT_MVT1 ;
MPRINT(SIN1):   run;

ERROR: Le(la) format $TRCHAGE est introuvable ou n'a pas pu être chargé(e).
ERROR: Le(la) format $NB est introuvable ou n'a pas pu être chargé(e).
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: Due to ERROR(s) above, SAS set option OBS=0, enabling syntax check mode. 
      This prevents execution of subsequent data modification statements.
WARNING: The data set WORK.MAJ_SIN may be incomplete.
```

Comment: There are some formats pre-defined on your side, but not on "platform SAS". Either find and bring these formats to "platform SAS", or use `option nofmterr` to suppress format missing error.

Comment: how can I apply this option: nofmterr option, you can give me an example?, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Is that log supposed to be from one SAS job?  If so it does not make sense as the language used for the system messages has changed and the setting of the FMTERR option also seems to have changed.

The first seems to have been run with this option setting:

```
options nofmterr ;
```

The second seems to have been run with this option setting:

```
options fmterr ;
```

So make sure to include the statement

```
options nofmterr ;
```

In your program before the step that is failing.

NOTE: If the formats can be found then the setting of the FMTERR option will not matter.  To find the formats make sure you have them in a SAS catalog (you can create formats using PROC FORMAT) and the catalog is listed in the set of locations SAS will search for formats in the FMTSEARCH system option.

Comment: thank you, i will try to do this function